# loading config file from default package vs from classpath

Tags: java, classpath, default-package, tinylog

I'm getting a crazy error while loading a config file in a JAX-RS application on jetty.

```
public class Configuration {
    public static final Properties config = new Properties();

    static {
        config.clear();

        try (InputStream inputStream = Configuration.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties")) {
            config.load(inputStream);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.error(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

If I put `config.properties` in default package, it is working fine. But when I load it with `java -cp config.properties` there is nothing in `config` object. I have examined these ways but it doesn't work.

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
Configuration.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
Configuration.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
```

The strange thing is that I use Tinylog as Logger in project and TinyLog loads its configuration file which is `tinylog.properties` in the same way:

```
/* I found this from Tinylog source code */
Configurator.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("tinylog.properties");
```

I'm feeding tinylog configuration via `java -cp tinylog.properties`. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

The `-cp` option takes a list of directories and jar files. It doesn't take properties files. You need to put the **directory** containing the `config.properties` file in the classpath.